# Sending a Forward to friend email but not adding to all subcribers

Tags: api, marketing-cloud

We have a client who has a wish list page - and they want a customer to be able to send the email to a friend showing them their wish list.

We can use the API to send an email but we do not want the email address added to all subscribers as the customer being sent the email has not opted in.

Is it possible to send an email without adding the customer to the database?

Cheers

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107669/sending-a-forward-to-friend-email-but-not-adding-to-all-subcribers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up a triggered send object, there is an option to select "Add Subscriber to List" under Subscriber Management. If you deselect this option, the recipient of the F2F email will not be added to All Subscribers list. I just tested this functionality.

Comment: Oh really so if the 'Add Subscriber to List'  isn't ticked it doesnt add them to all subscribers. I thought if you sent anyone an email from the platform it will always add them to ALL SUBSCRIBERS.

Comment: The subscriber will be added to the system in other ways (tracking logs) but based on the test I ran, they were not added to the All Subscribers list. I did not test if the triggered send hard bounces to see if they are added to All Subscribes with a status of "Held."

Comment: I'd be keen to see if anyone else has been able to achieve this. I've tested this and I can't create a Triggered Send with the 'Add Subscriber to List' checkbox deselected. Perhaps the behavior has changed. SFMC relies on subscribers for tracking, validation and more, so I'd be really surprised if this is possible.

Comment: I've also validated this, and Daniel is right, the email is sent. However, a couple of odd things: 1. The Subscriber **is created**,  they don't appear in All Subscribers, but you can find them in the Subscribers Data View. 2. viewing the send report in Tracking > Sends shows 0 emails were sent, when they were sent.